# How to get a gradient of a placeholder with default in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am working with an autoencoder. My tensorflow graph looks something like this: (input image) --conv2d--> (compressed representation) --deconv2d--> (reconstructed image).

I changed compressed representation tensor to be placeholder_with_default, so that I can plug in any value I want and see what is reconstructed. The default value that should be used when *compressed representation* is not fed is the result of conv2d.

However, the optimiser complains that:

```
LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: PlaceholderWithDefault
```

How can I let the graph know to just use the usual gradient at the optimisation stage? When *compressed representation* is not a placeholder everything works fine.

Comment: If you have replaced part of your network with a placeholder, why are you using the optimizer? I would assume that your network is already trained.

Comment: I prepared the graph thinking that it has to be able to work both for the optimisation and exploration of representation. How can you change structure of the graph after it was trained? Can I readily change back between placeholder and computational part, so I can switch between training and exploration?

Comment: You might want to look into saving your encoder, representation and decoder separately. Or you could try to build a separate decoder network and use `get_variable()` function to reuse your trained variables.

Comment: You can change structure of a graph after it's been created by using `tensorflow.contrib.graph_editor`

Comment: Also, you could define gradient for placeholder by using `gradient_override_map`

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to use a placeholder to feed in data - any tensor can be the target of the feed_dict argument in session.run(). Hence you should keep the compressed representation as a tensor and just assign it to what you want when you want to provide your own data in the feed_dict argument.